# When do temporaries passed to coroutines get destroyed?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am confused about the lifetime of temporaries passed to coroutine tasks.  Consider this example:

```
cppcoro::task<> UseObject(Object const& object);

cppcoro::task<> CallUseObject() {
    co_await UseObject(Object()); // is this valid?
}
```

If these were functions returning void, then the `Object()` passed to `UseObject` would be destroyed at the semi-colon (i.e. after `UseObject` completes).  However, I'm not sure if the same applies for coroutines.  Is passing a temporary to a routine by reference safe?  When do temporaries get destroyed if it isn't at the semi colon?

Furthermore, as a sanity check, is it always safe to write:

```
cppcoro::task<> CallUseObject() {
    Object stayingalive;
    co_await UseObject(stayingalive);
}
```

since `staying_alive` is destroyed after co_await finishes?

Comment: I'm tempted to say that `Object()` died at the end of the statement, but I could be wrong. Seem like coroutine is a great choice for 'pass by value'

Comment: If function calls coroutine that receives parameter by reference, the caller function is responsible for lifetime of the passed object, till coroutine completes. This actually same rule as for synchronous calls, but now you should also deal with case when function exited, but not completed, and all temporaries are destructed. co_await operator does not help, because this operator works on return value, which you get only after function exit.

Comment: My recent experience with vs2019 shows that your first example(Object()), destructor is not called till co_await ends.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually subject of an [open issue](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p0664r7.html#33) with the [current draft](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/n4775.pdf). To quote the issue:

> The intent is that copies/moves of parameters (if required) are created preserving the exact type (including references, r-references, etc). The wording in 11.4.4[dcl.fct.def.coroutine]/11 does not seem to express that clearly.

Based on that, it would seem that the coroutine frame will capture a reference to the temporary.

Since `co_await` is an expression, the temporary should get destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it appears. Whether your code above is safe or not will depend on whether the concrete implementation of the two coroutines involved makes it safe to `co_await` on a call to `UseObject` with a reference to a temporary. Specifically, note that what `co_await` does depends on both, the type of the expression it's applied to as well as the promise type of the coroutine it appears in. Additionally, `UseObject` (which we don't know the definition of) could, at least in principle, do all sorts of weird things with the reference it's given…

Comment: I think this half answers my question.  You're saying the coroutine frame should hold a reference.  The other half of the question is when the reference gets invalidated.  Does the object get destroyed before co_await finishes?  Or at the semi-colon.  Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: I would say it should indeed happen at the semicolon. `co_await` is an expression. The temporary that gets materialized when the prvalue `Object()` is bound to the reference will be destroyed at the end of the full expression.

Comment: OK.  Based on your comment, this code is safe because the coroutine stores a reference to a temporary that is destroyed after the coroutine is destroyed.  If you merge your answer and the comment, then I will accept the answer.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash I don't think it can be said that this is safe in general. Whether this is safe depends on what `co_await` will do. What `co_await` does depends on the type of the argument as well as the promise type of the coroutine in which it appears. All that can be said based on the information provided in your question is that the coroutine call will capture a reference to the temporary. Whether this is safe depends on the concrete implementation of the two coroutines…

Comment: Thanks for updating. I hope the committee simplifies the answers to these simple questions before they standardize coroutines.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash it's been voted into the standard, I don't think much is going to change. However, assuming that `co_await` on a call to `UseObject` does indeed wait until the `UseObject` invocation is done doing stuff with the reference, this will be safe (if we also assume that `UseObject` doesn't do anything stupid like use the reference to initialize a global variable that keeps it for later). I just tried to keep my answer correct in general. Especially considering someone may find this question in the future and could be led to believe that this would be a safe thing to do in general…